# How do I add an admin dashboard feature to my PSK app? And why can't I reach my admin.html page?

Tags: polymer-starter-kit

As soon as I unzipped and configured the PSK, I tried to add an `admin.html` page next to `index.html` from where I'd like to manage my application. However, when I try to reach it via `localhost:3000/admin`, I get redirected to `localhost:3000/admin#!/admin` where the original application, the one in `index.html` shows up, I think because of routing.

I tried removing the hashbang option from page.js, tried changing the `/` route to `/home`, all to no avail. The admin.html page doesn't want to show up.

How does one do that? Maybe I need to create another application all together and host it on `/admin`?

P.S. I am not asking about the security of the approach here. If you want to know anyway, I will try to manage security with firebase (still have to look into it). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in order to get to admin.html, you need to use ".html" in your URL. So try using localhost:3000/admin.html.

Second, assuming you've made no changes but to duplicate the index.html and rename it admin.html, this will still trigger the routing.  You'll need to either create new routing contexts to routing.js in order to control this page, which is a little awkward being it's essentially controlling two separate SPAs, or remove routing.js from your Vulcanized elements.html file so that it can be included only on the main app (index.html).  The second option also opens the possibility of having multiple routing.js files so for example your admin.html could essentially become it's own SPA controlled by routing.admin.js.

Good luck!

Comment: Problem was solved doing exactly what you told! 2nd solution. Thank you!